# sprintf zero pad on right side

Tags: go, printf

How to zero pad on the right side? This code zero pad to the left

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%06s", "45")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output

```
000045
```

What I want

```
450000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can space pad on the right with `fmt.Sprintf("%-6s", "45")`

You must do your own padding to pad with `0`:

```
// Zero PAD Right
func zpadr(s string, n int) string {
    n -= len(s)
    if n > 0 {
        s += strings.Repeat("0", n)
    }
    return s
}
```

Use like this: `fmt.Sprintf("%s", zpadr("45", 6))`